# Maintaining state, like counter, in aiohttp server

Tags: python, aiohttp

Is this proper way to go or is there some aiohttp specific way to maintain state information in a server?

Now it is just a counter but it could be something like reservations in a booking system.

```py
from aiohttp import web

counter = 0

async def handle(request):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    return web.Response(text=str(counter))

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes(
    [
        web.get("/", handle),
    ]
)

def main():
    web.run_app(app)
```

Comment: You can store state in a [mutable attribute on the app object](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/discussions/6804#discussioncomment-3066116).